# Thread pool executor with background and ui thread vs Async task in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-background

i am doing lot of work in background in android like downloading ,sending request to server and getting json data etc. I am using asynctask there but i have another way to do this work by using handler and executor etc. I want to know which one is better way when lot of background work are going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use AsyncTask.

If you look into the source code of AsyncTask, you'll find AsyncTask just uses ThreadPoolExecutor and Handler.